# Q: Laravel 5.1 Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

What is the best way to make an Authentication in Laravel 5? Would it be best to use the built-in Authentication? Should i use a package 
like [Sentinel](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0)? I'm looking for the most secure way to do a Authentication.
What can you recommend and why?

Comment: Sentinel is awesome. You should use it. It supports multiple levels of authentication / roles - and extremely flexible and scalable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel's built-in Auth is great and it can deal with anything, not matter how complex. Though Sentinel can help you deal with complex stuff more easily.

So if you just want to make a basic authentication, then you'll be just fine without Sentinel. Otherwise it'll be easier if you use it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i want the most secure method, so i think i will go with Sentinel, also because they have nice permissions solutions.